# excel spreadsheet not recalculating

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I noticed this today, a spreadsheet that I had made last year to track sales and handed off to another manager has since ceased to update formulas automatically.

Things I checked:

- I checked under formulas > calculation > auto update and it is in fact turned on
- I also double checked all my cells to make sure they aren't listed as text
- I also made sure they aren't using circular reference.
- I also tried using the "calculate now" button but that didn't do anything
- I also tried saving it locally and re-opening the spreadsheet (when i posted the question originally i had opened it up directly from an email), it was listed as read-only, even after saving it locally it's still not auto updating

If I click into each individual cell and click "enter" THEN my cells recalculate! How do I remedy the problem without recreating the spreadsheet entirely?

Comment: Might be worth selecting the entire column which has the formulas and selecting Data > Text To Columns > Finish. This has the same effect as clicking into each cell individually

Comment: i gave it a shot but it just crashed my spreadsheet lol

Comment: How about if you just select a few cells in the column and try it, does that update the results?

Comment: selecting a few cells within the column completely breaks the formulas, it adds a ' in front of the formula and cuts it down to like the first 12 characters of the formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the dependency table might be broken.  try `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F9`

Comment: the dependency table (aka dependency graph, dependency matrix) is excel's way of keeping track of which cells depend on other cells.  In this way, it determines which cells to update when a given cell is changed.  If this is corrupt somehow, excel will think that cells do not need to be updated when they actually do.  This key combination forces excel to recompute all cells and reconstruct the dependency matrix.